# Deploy List Definitions, content types and site columns on Office365

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I was wondering which is the best way to deploy our typical SharePoint artifacts such as list definitions, content types and site columns that we usually design in Visual Studio to a Office365 site collection.

I have been working on O365 for more than an year now and the only solution that I came up with is to create a sandboxed solution with no code and obviously deploy it to my site.

Unfortunately many clients nowadays don't even want to hear the word "sandboxed", so is there an alternative solution?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office 365 Patterns and Practices has examples on how to do that:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP

Mainly in https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples you will find all the items you are looking for.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Solutions/Provisioning.Framework.Cloud.Async contains a fully built solution with an xml based templating engine to fully provision sites/site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox solutions are still very  applicable, especially in O365 .CSOM with PowerShell is another viable alternative solution .[This thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98825/office-365-developing-site-columns-and-content-types-declaratively) has discussed about this topic. Please refer to below article :

[Programmatically creating Site Columns and Content Types using the App Model](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-site-columns-content-types-app-model/)